# QLPreviewController with ALAsset items

Tags: ios, alassetslibrary, alasset, quicklook, qlpreviewcontroller

I'm getting a list of ALAsset items (images and videos) from a specific photo album and trying to view them using a QLPreviewController.

Unfortunately because ALAsset doesn't provide a real file url, just the "assets-library://" type url, viewing them in a QLPreviewController using just that url isn't possible.

My only solution was to first copy each of those ALAssets into the Documents folder inside my app (getting the raw data from an ALAssetRepresentation and saving it in a file), and viewing those with the QLPreviewController, but it ends up being too slow and sluggish when the number or size of files gets bigger.

Is there any way to get this done? Is there any other way to enumerate through the items inside a photo album that would return a true filesystem URL? Or should I just try to make my own preview controller with UIImageViews and MPMovieControllers and recreate all the functionality (swipe, share, etc)?